# filepicker.io widget not visible on chrome & IE

Tags: javascript, iframe, filepicker.io

I am trying to record video from user webcam using filepicker.io and store it in my Amazon S3 bucket.

I am stuck up here.Below code works fine in firefox but not on chrome & IE. The abc iframe src is not set by filepicker api, so the contents remain blank. I verified that 3rd part cookies are enabled on chrome. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<iframe id="abc" name="abc" height="500" width="500" frameborder="0"> abc </iframe>
<script src="https://api.filepicker.io/v0/filepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
filepicker.setKey("AeE9yA21xTpiOQ3JQm938z");
 // alert('before');
    filepicker.getFile(filepicker.MIMETYPES.ALL, {
    'multiple': false, 'container': 'abc',
    'services':[filepicker.SERVICES.VIDEO]
     }, function(response){
          alert(JSON.stringify(response));
     });
//  alert('end');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding other sources besides just webcam video? I understand you only want webcam, but I'd be interested in seeing if anything changes. I was able to get it to work in chrome here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gy7nr/

Comment: Hi Brett thanks for the reply. I tried with 3 services. filepicker.SERVICES.VIDEO,filepicker.SERVICES.COMPUTER,filepicker.SERVICES.FACEBOOK. Still no luck. This works fine on firefox. Also jsfiddle on chrome is showing this correctly. For some reason chrome & IE are not showing this.

Comment: Reasearch : Also I extracted the iframe src dynamically assigned by filepicker code from firefox using firebug and force assigned to iframe src to check if chrome will be able display the widget.[https://www.filepicker.io/dialog/open/?m=*%2F*&amp;key=AeE9yA21xTpiOQ3JQm938z&amp;id=1349789071455&amp;referrer=&amp;iframe=true&amp;s=13,1,3]. This works fine on chrome & IE. So on chrome the src for the iframe was never set [atleast with the configuration I have.]

Comment: Research : I placed the code in main update in this page, please try opening it on latest version of chrome [22.0.1229.79 m]. http://www.interviewcup.com/test.php .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the iframe wasn't included in the DOM yet. It worked for me when I put the javascript code inside the onReady call from jquery:

http://www.filepicker.io/api/file/4wW3A6BwQYaPDNBENcau?dl=false

Comment: Excellent!! This works fine. I am proceeding with onReady call approach. Thanks for your help Bret !!